# Head phones not out puting sound

Tags: sound, headphones

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu gnome edition last night and have been pretty happy with it. The only problem is that I plug in my head phones, the sound still comes out of my laptop's built in speakers. I've tested multiple headphones and none are working.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` , to open terminal/command line. Type `alsamixer`, hit enter. This will bring up Alsa Mixer application.[image]

Do you see `Auto-Mut` part? Do you have it enabled? If not, speakers won't be muted. Using left/right arrow keys navigate to it, and using up/down, enable this option.

Do you see your line  with a vertical bar? What do you have bellow? If it is MM, it means your headphones are muted, so no sound will be comming out. Using right/left keys navigate to headphones, unmute them by pressing m on your keyboard, up/down arrows bring the volume level to desired percentage. Master volume is also important - if you have that muted or at 00, nothing will come out. Change it just like I already explained

For  some reason 14.04 version ships with volume muted by default, which is very weird. Had that issue when installed on chromebook and when updated on my Toshiba laptop from 13.10. Pretty sure Auto-Mute is disabled by default as well

Comment: When I go into alsamixer headphones and auto-mut are not options

Answer (score 0):

right click speaker icon on sys tray,select audio settings,should bring up a menu with a header called "Audio and video settings" click "audio hardware setup"
click "sound card" line and choose device.
this works in 15.10 at least for me.